# Anyone have a example of an functional simplecart(js) with checkout through email ?

Tags: simplecart

Anyone have a example of an functional simplecart(js) with checkout through email ?

so i can change for my code.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code in a separate php file. I used sendcart.php.

```
<?php
 $to = 'youremail@email.com';
 $subject = 'Your Subject';
 $content = $_POST;
 $body = '';
 for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) {
     $name = 'item_name_'.$i;
     $quantity =  'item_quantity_'.$i;
     $price = 'item_price_'.$i;
     $body .= 'item #'.$i.': ';
     $body .= $content[$name].' '.$content[$quantity].' '.$content[$price];
     $body .= '<br>';
 }
 $headers = 'From: youremail@email.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: youremail@email.com' . "\r\n" .
         '   X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
 Header('Location: thankyou.php');
 ?>
```

Then in your html file, include the following line inside the script tag.

```
simpleCart({  
   checkout: { 
      type: "SendForm" , 
      url: "sendcart.php",
      method: "POST",
   }
});
```